# Recursively fetch all files from shared folder using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pywin32

I have established connection with a Windows Shared drive using Pywin32

```
import win32net
data = {
    'remote': r"\\server\shared",
    'local': '',
    'username': 'username',
    'password': 'password'
}

win32net.NetUseAdd(None, 2, data)
```

I need to list out all the files present in the shared folder, similar to `os.walk(path)`.

What are the possible ways to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Check [[ME.TimGolden]: Python for Win32 Extensions Help](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/contents.html)
((officially) referenced by [[GitHub]: mhammond/pywin32 - Python for Windows (pywin32) Extensions](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32) which is a *Python* wrapper ove *WinAPI*s).

*win32net.NetUseAdd* wraps [[MS.Learn}: NetUseAdd function (lmuse.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmuse/nf-lmuse-netuseadd).
[[MS.Learn]: USE_INFO_2 structure (lmuse.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmuse/ns-lmuse-use_info_2) (wrapt by [[ME.TimGolden]: PyUSE_INFO_2 Object](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/PyUSE_INFO_2.html) - that you used) states:

> `ui2_local`
>
> Type: **LMSTR**
>
> A pointer to a string that contains the local device name (for example, drive E or LPT1) being redirected to the shared resource. The constant DEVLEN specifies the maximum number of characters in the string. This member can be **NULL**. For more information, see the following Remarks section.

All you have to do is:

1. **Provide a local name** (that is not in use)
2. Once the connection is successful, use that (just as any "regular" local drive)

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys

import win32net as wnet


def main(*argv):
    local_drive = "y:"
    data = {
        "remote": r"\\localhost\share_cfati",
        "local": local_drive,
        "username": "user",  # @TODO - cfati: Modified to hide sensitive data
        "password": "***",  # @TODO - cfati: Modified to hide sensitive data
    }

    try:
        res = wnet.NetUseAdd(None, 2, data)
        #print(res)
    except:
        print("Error adding connection:", sys.exc_info())
        return -1

    print("Items in the shared folder:\n{:}".format(os.listdir(local_drive)))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.\n")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q075267137]> sopr.bat
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> net share
>
> Share name   Resource                        Remark
>
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ADMIN$       C:\WINDOWS                      Remote Admin
> C$           C:\                             Default share
> E$           E:\                             Default share
> F$           F:\                             Default share
> G$           G:\                             Default share
> H$           H:\                             Default share
> IPC$                                         Remote IPC
> L$           L:\                             Default share
> M$           M:\                             Default share
> N$           N:\                             Default share
> share_cfati  L:\Share\cfati
> share_pub_ro L:\Share\pub_ro
> share_pub_rw L:\Share\pub_rw
> The command completed successfully.
>
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> net use
> New connections will not be remembered.
>
> There are no entries in the list.
>
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.10_test0\Scripts\python.exe" ./code00.py
> Python 3.10.9 (tags/v3.10.9:1dd9be6, Dec  6 2022, 20:01:21) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> Items in the shared folder:
> ['.DS_Store', 'a.py', 'b', 'c', 'code00.py', 'commander.dmg', 'copy_sdk-aars.sh', 'cstrike1.6.zip', 'dedus', 'doublecmd.xml', 'ifm', 'pula', 'py2713.tgz']
>
> Done.
>
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> net use
> New connections will not be remembered.
>
>
> Status       Local     Remote                    Network
>
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> OK           Y:        \\localhost\share_cfati   Microsoft Windows Network
> The command completed successfully.
>
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> net use /delete y:
> y: was deleted successfully.
>
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> net use
> New connections will not be remembered.
>
> There are no entries in the list.
> ```

**Notes**:

- This is the equivalent of ***Map network drive...*** feature from *Win* *UI*
- Generally, when done with a resource it's best to release it. I removed the connection (`net use /delete y:`), but that can be also done from the code via win32net.NetUseDel*
- File (folder) browsing itself is not part of this question (at least I don't consider it to be), as it's a different (stand alone) topic. Check [[SO]: How do I list all files of a directory? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48393588/4788546) for a thorough analysis on how to do it